# Why Map.entry::getKey and Map.entry::getValue doesn't work when sorting hashmap in a stream?

Tags: java, sorting

I'm trying to sort a HashMap using a stream :

```
public class sortByValue implements Sorting{
    @Override
    public LinkedHashMap<String,Integer> sort(Map map) {
        return map.entrySet().stream().
                              sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue()).
                              collect(Collectors.toMap(
                                        Map.Entry::getKey,
                                        Map.Entry::getValue,
                                        (oldValue, newValue) -> oldValue, LinkedHashMap::new));
    }
}
```

But it gives me an error :

`Non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context`  it is on the functions
`Map.Entry::getKey,Map.Entry::getValue` But I saw the same example on the website.Maybe someone understands what the mistake is?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix the error, change the parameter from a raw `Map`

```
Map map
```

to a typed `Map`:

```
Map<String, Integer> map
```

Giving:

```
public Map<String, Integer> sort(Map<String, Integer> map) {
return map.entrySet().stream().
        sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue()).
        collect(Collectors.toMap(
                Map.Entry::getKey,
                Map.Entry::getValue,
                (oldValue, newValue) -> oldValue, LinkedHashMap::new));
}
```

Or to make it work with *any* map type:

```
public <K, V extends Comparable<V>> Map<K, V> sort(Map<K, V> map) {
```

Note that the return type doesn’t need to be `LinkedHashMap`. As per [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) you should always use the abstract type where possible.

I haven't looked deeply into it, but I suspect you have encountered an unintentional match with a synthetic method.

Generics has some weird aspects when you use raw types, which are to be avoided.

Comment: Thanks you. It 's strange that I wrote it myself and wrote it , and the ide itself corrected it  .

Answer (score 1):

Replace method's parameter from `Map map` to `Map<String, Integer> map` and it will work correctly. Currently your map generic types are mismatching.

Or if you want to make it more generic, then you can do it like this:
`public <S, T extends Comparable<T>>LinkedHashMap<S, T> sort(Map<S, T> map) {`

Answer (score 0):

To add to this - this issue can also crop up if you have a map in a lambda parameter. You need to type your lambda parameter rather than replying on the implicit typing. I had this problem when reducing to a hashmap like below:

```
map
    .stream()
    .reduce(
        new HashMap<>(),
        (a, b) -> { /* some reducer */}
        /* The types below in the lambda function are needed! */
        (final Map<Key, Integer> a, final Map<Key, Integer> b) -> Stream.of(a, b)
            .flatMap(map -> map.entrySet().stream())
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                Map.Entry::getKey,
                Map.Entry::getValue,
                Integer::sum
            ))
        );
```